# PHP and SQL Last Login

Tags: php, sql, ip-address

Okay, so I'm going to try to insert the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` in the users column of the database.  So It's like:

```
username |  192.168.0.1
```

I tried using insert, to make it insert into the column and overwrite after each log in, but It just makes a whole new row.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`last-login`) VALUES ('$ip')");
```

So, my question is how do I make it overwrite a brand new IP and insert it in the users last login colum each time they login?

Please help.

Comment: Try using UPDATE instead of INSERT

Comment: Have you tried looking at the mysql update command?

Comment: @BugFinder No, where can I learn more info on it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp start there, and do the whole tutorial on SQL.

Comment: Prepared statements AND update instead of insert: 

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the UPDATE statement and then update the column. I'm sure there is a username field inside the table? If so.. Something like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last-login='$ip' WHERE username='$username'");
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Works, had to fix a slight error.  `last-login` = '$ip' WHERE `username` = '$username'");

Comment: @user1581488 if you found answer, do not forget to mark it as the answer, a `tick` below the vote count.

Answer (score 0):

Try the update command:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html